# multiple/nested begin/end, function statements in procedures in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i´m new to PL/SQL and don´t know how to write it clean and with good practice. I read and watched a view tutorials but these examples were much easyier than my procedure. To create a "large" readable, clean procedure i would use multiple and/or nested begin/ends and functions like this:

`begin 
 statement...
 function...
 end function
 exception
end`

begin.... and so on

but i´m not sure if this is a lean way to write PL/SQL. I need multiple selects on different tables, find rows use them and isert and update rows in different tables. All that in a single procedure. In general i would use begin/end for new Statements, declares for just locally used variables and functions for operations on the result of a statement. Would this be good practice?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is purely something which you can read and get through. I mean you can refer good books and do it yourself. Please read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`begin...end;` alone does nothing. You only need a nested block if it has a `declare` or `exception` that makes sense at that level.

For example, the inner `begin`/`end` keywords here are pointless, and you can just remove them:

```
begin
    ...

    begin
        processing steps
    end;

    ...
end;
```

A nested block is useful if we want to handle some exception in a nested block only (for example, handle `no_data_found` exceptions for a particular lookup, or file operations for `utl_file`). This is often better than having exception handlers at the end, especially for procedures with a lot of processing steps:

```
begin
    ...

    begin
        processing steps
    exception
        when no_data_found then...
    end;

    ...
end;
```

Similarly, we might declare a local variable or constant etc with the scope of the nested block only. This is probably a less usual requirement than the exception example, but there are cases where it could be useful:

```
begin
    ...

    declare
        x constant integer := whatever();
    begin
        processing steps using x
    end;

    ...
end;
```

If the procedure is complex with a large number of steps, you might consider ways to break it up into smaller reusable modules.